# where can I find some good examples for beginner on J2ME Polish

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I am a beginner in the mobile application developemnt. I just started with J2ME, I have to work with J2ME Polish. Can any one suggest me where can I find examples on the J2ME polish like the hello world program for a java developer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded Polish, you already have them in the *samples* folder. The given examples probably get you started. The online help is also quite extensive.